# Python: How to remove values for weekend in a panda series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a range of daily values. I want to remove the weekend (Sat + Sun) period and the accompanying values. How do I do so? Thank you

```
df=pd.read_excel(input_file, sheet_name='daily', usecols='A:D', na_values='ND', index_col=0, header=0)
df.index.names = ['Period']
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
 
q= pd.Series(df['Values'], index=df.index)
```

```
**Period Values**
20-Jan-89 3
27-Jan-89 4
3-Feb-89 2
10-Feb-89 5
17-Feb-89 3
24-Feb-89 5
3-Mar-89 5
10-Mar-89 6
17-Mar-89 4
24-Mar-89 5
31-Mar-89 7
7-Apr-89 6
14-Apr-89 6
21-Apr-89 4
28-Apr-89 7
5-May-89 5
12-May-89 6
19-May-89 5
26-May-89 7
2-Jun-89 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us do

```
q = q[q.index.dayofweek<5]
```

Comment: 0 = Monday, 7 = Sunday